# "Collision Map" in SpriteKit

Tags: ios, ios8, sprite-kit, 2d-games, skspritenode

I'm building a **2D game** using `SpriteKit` and this is what I would like to achieve.

Imagine a vertically scrolling `SKSpriteNode` which represents a tall building. Building is represented using simple image and has a physics body set with `+ (SKPhysicsBody *)bodyWithTexture:(SKTexture*)texture size:(CGSize)size;` (introduced with iOS 8) so it is closely following the building's path.

Some parts of the building are special. Colliding with those parts should be yielding a special collision action. For example, touching the wall of the building would fire an *action 1* but touching any of the windows would fire an *action 2*.

What I haven't been able to do is in some way define those "special blocks" of the building.

I was thinking about making some kind of a "Collision Map" for each of the building's sprite images which would be basically a transparent image with non-transparent blocks determining a collideable parts of the building. Simple example shown bellow (left: building image, right: collision map image):

[image: Building image] 
[image: Collision map image]

The problem with this approach is that when setting a `SKPhysicsBody` on a "Collision Map" image like the one above, the body is not applied to all blocks but it wraps around just one of those separate blocks. In other words: one physics body can be applied to only one, continuous block in image.

To conclude, I would like to know which approach are you using when determining non-continuous collision maps.

P.s.: building's `SKSpriteNode` is represented with multiple unique texture images which are scrolling vertically, one after another.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just an idea:
Can't you use two Sprites for the building which are positioned at the same place:
- one represents the physics body of your building (the left one from your image)
- invert your collision map image to get a single physics body block. The special areas should overlap the non special area by one pixel

Hope you understood what I mean. It's just an idea

Comment: thanks for posting your idea. One question: how would I be able to determine collision with special areas?

Comment: You can define two different collision categories and distinguish  inside of:     func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
            let category = contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask | contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask
if category == collisionExtraCategory | collisionShipCategory || category == collisionExtraCategory | collisionShieldCategory {

Comment: Sorry. Code formatting in a comment is not really possible. The idea is that both sprites have a different category. Inside of didBeginContact you can check if a collision took place with sprite A or B.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to find a solution based on your idea.